# How i can add data from database to HashMap in Spring and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsf, hashmap

I would like to know how i can add data from database to HashMap in Spring with Hibernate to choose this in dropdown in JSF file.

I try do this in that way:

It is query from DAO file:

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public List<Groups> getNameGroup() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<Groups> list = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery("SELECT GRNAME FROM Groups").list();

    return list;
}
```

In this way i add this data from database to list:

```
public List<Groups> getListagrup() {
    listagrup = new ArrayList<Groups>();
    listagrup = getGroupService().getNameGroup();
    System.out.println("logowanie: " + listagrup);


    return listagrup;
}
```

And i want add list values to HashMap :

```
public void init() {
    groupsnames = new HashMap<Groups,Groups>();
    groupsnames.put(listagrup.get(1),listagrup.get(1));
}
```

This is fragment JSF file which i want choose this values from HAshMap:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="title" value="#{scheduleBean.title}" style="width:150px">

  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Group Name" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
  <f:selectItems value="#{scheduleBean.groupsnames}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

So, in this case i dont have data in dropdown. what i can do to  add data from database to HashMap in Spring with Hibernate to choose this in dropdown in JSF file?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please be sure to read this guide to [asking good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, your code was badly formatted - I've edited that.  However - you also want to make absolutely clear what you're asking - the behaviour you see and *what you expected* from your code.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a problem with how you populate your `Hashmap`. 
Usually you have a key-value pair where the **key** is used to locate the paired **value**

```
groupsnames = new HashMap<Groups,Groups>();
groupsnames.put(listagrup.get(1),listagrup.get(1));
```

in your code above, you assigned your `Group` object as your **key**

Does `Groups` contain a primary key? It might be easier if you set the key to your `Hashmap` as `String` or `int` depending on your primary key:

```
groupsnames = new HashMap<String,Groups>();
groupsnames.put(listagrup.get(1).getYourPrimaryKey,listagrup.get(1));
```

This might lead you to the right direction on your JSF (you didnt post your `Group` class). Hope this helps.